# Command line compiling VB.NET project via Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to compile my [Visual Basic .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) project named *Myproject.sln* via command line commands. I need to build and compile that solution.

My Visual Basic .NET compiler is called vbc.exe. Any idea how I do that thing?

I am using Visual Studio 2005 , and I have already read Microsoft's tutorial, "[Building from the Command Line (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25fz1td5%28VS.80,printer%29.aspx)".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .NET framework (version 2 and above) comes with a command line build utility called [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).
You can use this to build your Visual Studio project/solution files.

From the command line:

```
msbuild Myproject.sln
```

Comment: +1, You may also need to set up your environment for this with vcvarsall.bat (e.g. "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat")

Comment: Visual Studio comes with a command prompt already configured via the Start Menu, something like 'Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt'

However, if you don't want to use that, MSBuild lives inside the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\V2.0.50727 folder.

Comment: Hi I added path where that file located on my pc to system variables,
but still that command not recognized .

Comment: Opening up the 'Visual Studio Command Prompt' works fine here. Just type msbuild (on it's own) and you should get a msbuild error message about misssing parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Just run [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) and specify the .sln file as a command line option:

```
msbuild myproject.sln /p:buildmode=release
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using MSBuild. That's probably the best approach.

Your .sln file is a valid MSBUild project file, so if you open the Visual Studio command prompt from the start menu and browse to your project location,

```
 c:\...\msbuild MyFile.sln
```

... for example, it should just work.

Comment: Saying the sln file is a valid MSBuild file is a bit of a stretch. There's lots of information out there about crafting MSBuild files, and they're all dealing with the XML files, using the MSBuild schema, such as .csproj and .vbproj. MSBuild does understand solution files, but I wouldn't describe them as MSBuild files.